# Data binding to Textboxes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
   Dim myconn As New SqlConnection("Server=server,Trusted_Connection=True,Database=database")
    'selects from mt table linking the current pc to a row
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * from idset " & vbcrlf &
    "Where pcname= '" & pcname & "'"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn)

    da.Fill(ds, "Setup")


    txtClientID.DataBindings.Add("text", ds.Tables("idset"), "CLID")
```

I don't know why its not working for some reason its not filling the data set did I declare something wrong?

Comment: Your edit made the currently accepted answer appear incorrect, because it referred to an error that was no longer present. Since you didn't comment on why you accepted [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25748228/240733), it seemed better to roll back your edit than to update the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it don't work is because you specify that the incoming table should be mapped to a table named `Setup`. Your data set doesn't contain a table named `Setup`, so the incoming table will be named... well, `Setup`.

Try this instead:

```
da.Fill(ds, "idset")
```

Also, I ***strongly*** suggest you:

- Set [option strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) on
- Always use [parameterized/prepared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) SQL queries.
- Always use the [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement when working with disposable objects.

Seriously.

---

The best way to debug bindings is to use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(v=vs.110).aspx) and handle the [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.bindingcomplete(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```vb
Private bs As BindingSource
Private ds As DataSet

Private Sub Initialize(pcname As String)

    Me.ds = New DataSet()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Server=server,Trusted_Connection=True,Database=database")
        connection.Open()
        Using command As New SqlCommand()
            command.Connection = connection
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * from [idset] Where [pcname] = @pcname;"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcname", pcname)
            Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                adapter.Fill(Me.ds, "idset")
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Me.bs = New BindingSource(Me.ds, "idset")

    AddHandler bs.BindingComplete, AddressOf Me.HandleBindingCompleted

    Me.txtClientID.DataBindings.Add("Text", Me.bs, "CLID")

End Sub

Private Sub HandleBindingCompleted(sender As Object, e As BindingCompleteEventArgs)
    If (Not e.Exception Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorText)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry about that I had named the table setup. My boss came in early and changed names on me still rooting out errors in other place :(. Will look at that.

Comment: Changed around still not getting anything. The sql statement against the server directly through ssms works fine pulling up the row i want just it not seeming to bind.

Comment: Thanks alot i have alot more reading to do now to understand what you have done.