# Getting text from databound label

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a `label` that is bound to a `BindingSource`. The label text populates correctly, but I cannot retrieve that information. In other words, I can SEE the correct text, but I cannot use it in my code as follows:

```
Public Sub LoadImage(ByVal caseNum As String, ByVal commnum As String)
    If Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.GetData(caseNum, commnum).Count > 0 Then
        Try
            Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DevGISDataSet.spGetLOMCDocumentPath, caseNum, commnum)

            Dim docPath As New BindingSource
            docPath = Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathBindingSource

            Me.bnTIF.BindingSource = docPath

            Me.lblDocPath.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", docPath, "DocPath", True))

            Dim currentPath As String = Nothing

            currentPath = Me.lblDocPath.Text
            MessageBox.Show(Me.lblDocPath.Text)

            Me.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Image not available. Please check FEMA and CAMSIS.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

No error is thrown, the messagebox is blank. This method works with textboxes on other forms.

**Using binding handler**

```
Public Sub LoadImage(ByVal caseNum As String, ByVal commnum As String)
    If Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.GetData(caseNum, commnum).Count > 0 Then
        Try
            Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DevGISDataSet.spGetLOMCDocumentPath, caseNum, commnum)

            Dim docPath As New BindingSource
            docPath = Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathBindingSource

            Me.bnTIF.BindingSource = docPath
            'Me.dgDocPath.DataSource = docPath

            AddHandler docPath.BindingComplete, AddressOf Me.HandleBindingCompleted

            Me.lblDocPath.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", docPath, "DocPath", True))
            Me.txtDocPath.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", docPath, "DocPath", True))

            Me.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Image not available. Please check FEMA and CAMSIS.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleBindingCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As BindingCompleteEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Test")
    If (Not e.Exception Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorText)
        MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorText)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No error")
    End If
End Sub
```

Even the "Test" message box fails to appear.

**Calling this method**

```
Public Sub LoadLOMCImage(ByVal casenum As String, ByVal commnum As String)
    Try
        DisposeLOMCForm()

        Dim LOMCtif As New frmLOMCTiff
        LOMCtif.LoadImage(casenum, commnum)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error finding LOMC image: " & ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I call the LoadImage Sub from a separate form. Again, the data passed correctly, I can read the data correctly using the `GetData` method of the `TableAdapter`. I can set the `BindingSource` to a `DataGridView`, but I have the same problem: I can see the rows of data, but cannot access the row with an index of 0 (basic exception, index out of range, etc).

**Using suggested code:**

```
Public Sub LoadImage(ByVal caseNum As String, ByVal commnum As String)
    If Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.GetData(caseNum, commnum).Count > 0 Then
        Try
            Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DevGISDataSet.spGetLOMCDocumentPath, caseNum, commnum)

            Dim docPath As New BindingSource
            docPath = Me.SpGetLOMCDocumentPathBindingSource

            Me.bnTIF.BindingSource = docPath

            Dim b1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", docPath, "DocPath", True)

            AddHandler b1.BindingComplete, AddressOf Me.HandleBindingCompleted

            Me.lblDocPath.DataBindings.Add(b1)

            Dim currentPath As String = Nothing

            currentPath = Me.lblDocPath.Text
            MessageBox.Show(b1.Control.Text)

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentPath) Then
                If currentPath.Contains(".TIF") Then
                    LoadTIF()
                End If

                If currentPath.Contains(".pdf") Then
                    LoadPDF()
                End If
            End If

            'FindImage()

            Me.Show()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Image not available. Please check FEMA and CAMSIS.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub HandleBindingCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As BindingCompleteEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}: {1}", e.Binding.BindingMemberInfo.BindingMember, e.Binding.Control.Text))
    If (Not e.Exception Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ErrorText)
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, the binding is successful, but I cannot access the label text.

Comment: No error thrown is by-design. Better handle the `BindingComplete` event and look at the `Exception` property of the event argument. See the last part of my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25748228/1842065

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå thank you for your help. I integrated that code into mine, but it doesn't even appear that the event fires even though I've added the handler. Any ideas as to what may be happening?

Comment: Hard to guess without a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå see edits

Comment: May I ask from where you invoke the method?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå see edits, the best I can do to answer the question.

Comment: Each binding needs to handle the `BindingCompleted` event: http://pastebin.com/p7uLXNnh

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, sorry for the delay. I ran your code and it works, but I still can't access the label text. I don't know what else to do!

Comment: I guess your only option is to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, you are right, sorry, I have edited it my post.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I should also add that the HandleBindingCompleted event is firing twice, not sure why? I stepped through the debugger, but couldn't figure it out.